# Expand an output glob pattern

Tags: linux, bash

How can I implement `create-one-file`?

```
function create-one-file () {
  local content="$1"
  local glob="$2"  # no assumptions can be made here except that the location exists
  echo "$content" > "$glob"
}

mkdir -p xxx/{a,b,c}
create-one-file "content" "xxx/*/thefile"
```

I would like it to expand to **any** one of the possible destinations - just one, any one.

As it is implemented, it does not expand at all:

```
bash: xxx/*/thefile: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why not just `create-one-file "content" xxx/*/thefile`? And ignore the rest.

Comment: It  you want to put the content in any directory, which ever it is, you could just do `echo "$content" >xxx/a/thefile`.  No need to mess with wildcards if you only need it once, and you already know the directories that will be there.  What do you want exactly?  Ask about the problem or the requirement, not about your solution to something we do not know about (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Nic3500 obviously the directory tree structure is unknown to the function

Comment: @KamilCuk looks like a plan. I will try that